# Decrypt with public key?

Tags: java, security, cryptography, rsa

I've made a mistake when I was writing a promgram in Java.

```
package cf.huzpsb.jnip.security;

import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Cipher {
    private static final byte[] pub = Base64.getDecoder().decode("MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCUjb+/Ea3i9W53tASAu5OJ8vxf7+7oGberM5B6GIfu2uBMD0YfaQuGqInREop6kho7AHYd4oCq68fhQ4DbAtE+RSy9Us4sCMpvvE4luLWoR3iZQtii7hyIoDSeXGaNVu6L3xbjFji7kSDPpWubdCuD6dCVYD5kS2N07m74d5grOwIDAQAB");
    private static final byte[] pri = Base64.getDecoder().decode("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");

    public static String encrypt(String text) {
        try {
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pri);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
            javax.crypto.Cipher cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
            cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Failed";
        }
    }

    public static String decrypt(String text) {
        try {
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pub);
            PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);
            javax.crypto.Cipher cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
            cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(text)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've used the wrong key when trying to encrypt/decrypt the data.
However, the code didn't generate any exception.

If I compile and run:

```
String str = Cipher.encrypt("uwu");
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(Cipher.decrypt(str));
```

The console would show:

```
GrKyCCML73yuJN/fsdevN00eOvWUDl7MTpW50iWhhnhqhMxelWPEQ4I2A7PPd0G8flVaZrabAIsYNNUBpEg96x+8zj3ZTh5u9rXbhJKbzHXSMbsuPCY39WqUOf6qqqWRxGL44E3ltIdE/wQr7XeRvqJa4Z089mSxl6VYB468BnA=
uwu
```

Although I've fixed the mistake, I still have a question:

What's going on here? Why did it seemingly running "properly"?

---

Edit:

I've seen some may say that it's a type of "sign". But if that's the case, is there a way that I read the data without either key, if I don't care whether or not the data is tampered? Why or why not? Thanks!

Comment: How would a decryption program know you used the wrong key?  It will happily accept any key you provide it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey:But why did it produced the correct answer? As you can see, it printed "uwu" correctly.

Comment: Encrypting with the private key will work, because that is what is also done when you sign something with your private key. The normal direction is encrypt with public, decrypt with private, but the other direction works just as well (but is generally the wrong choice if you want to keep the data private), but it is a method which can be used so recipients know that the encryption was performed by the owner of the private key (hence why it is generally used for signing).

Comment: In other words, the fact this works is correct and entirely expected for asymmetrical cryptography systems like RSA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to *encrypt* data using RSA with a private key doesn't make sense. However, instead of throwing an exception when trying to do so, the `Cipher` class does something a little different. It assumes that you want to perform a signature operation and that you are supplying just the *payload* portion of the signature. It will then apply the PKCS1 padding string directly to your data, in this case the padding is 0x00 0x01 followed by as many 0xff 0xff ... 0xff 0x00 bytes as needed to fill out the length of the RSA block (128 bytes in this case) apply the exponentiation primitive with the private exponent.
Thus the padded contents look like this in hex:

```
0001ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00757775
```

Proper PKCS1 signing requires that the data is hashed and then encapsulated into a DigestInfo ASN.1 structure, but Cipher doesn't do that. The Signature class will do that however.

The result can only be verified (or "decrypted") with the correct public key. You can't get the plaintext unless you have the public key.